# Google maps API, waypoints, stopover true/false option give different results when using departureTime for specific open(summer)/closed(winter) roads

Tags: google-maps-api-3

When following [Google API Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#DirectionsRequests) i ran into a problem. I cannot find a solution to get this working correctly. Seems like it has to be a google issue.

If you check the images and snippet example you can see between waypoint A end B there is a road that is only open during summertime. During wintertime closed and gets a longer route which is normal.

When stopover is set to FALSE (during summertime) then the route is correct but there are no legs anymore. I need those legs between the waypoints. When triple checking the google API i cannot find why this behavior occurs. I'm aware some things are not working with TRANSIT but this is not the case here.

So i need the SHORT summer route with stopovers and with leg information as result. Any ideas to get this?

[Image: stopover=false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ep6BQ.png)

[Image: stopover=true](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyQcC.png)

When switching between stopover mode change 2 vars at line 36-37

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <style type="text/css"> 
            html { height: 100% }
            body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3";></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var directionDisplay;
            var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            var map;
            var wptruefalse;

            function initialize() {
                directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
                var myOptions = {
                    zoom: 6,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
                calcRoute();
            }

            function calcRoute() {
                var first = new google.maps.LatLng(61.84448683734486, 8.85223388671875);
                var second = new google.maps.LatLng(61.75298123367897, 9.078826904296875);
                var start = new google.maps.LatLng(61.484039,7.645798);
                var end = new google.maps.LatLng(61.944118091023746,7.97882080078125);
                var request = {
                    origin: start,
                    destination: end,
                    waypoints: [{location: first, stopover: wptruefalse},
                        {location: second, stopover: wptruefalse}],
                    optimizeWaypoints: true,
                    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
                    drivingOptions: {
                        departureTime: new Date("08/08/2018")
                    },
                };
                directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                        var route = response.routes[0];
                        var summaryPanel = document.getElementById("directions_panel");
                        summaryPanel.innerHTML = "";
                        // For each route, display summary information.
                        for (var i = 0; i < route.legs.length; i++) {
                            var routeSegment = i + 1;
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += "<b>Route Segment: " + routeSegment + "</b><br />";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].start_address + " to ";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].end_address + "<br />";
                            summaryPanel.innerHTML += route.legs[i].distance.text + "<br /><br />";
                        }
                    } else {
                        alert("directions response " + status);
                    }
                });
            }
            
            function doClick(myRadio) {
                if (myRadio.value === "true") {
                    wptruefalse = true;
                } else {
                    wptruefalse = false;
               }
               calcRoute();
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="initialize()">
        <div id="map_canvas" style="float:left;width:70%;height:100%;"></div>
        <div id="control_panel" style="float:right;width:30%;text-align:left;padding-top:20px">
        API Key is needed to test properly
        <form>
            <input type="radio" name="wpradio" onclick="doClick(this);" value="true" checked> True
            <input type="radio" name="wpradio" onclick="doClick(this);" value="false"> False
        </form>

            <div id="directions_panel" style="margin:20px;background-color:#FFEE77;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you need the legs?

Comment: I need the legs to have the distance and time between way points. The issue is in the sample with the road in Norway. Closed during winter, open in summer but doesn't work with stopover. For me a Google bug.